# Mac Mail "Reply-To" address

Tags: macos, email

Mac Mail is changing my "reply to" email address on my emails. I have several accounts set up in Mail, and when I send an email from one account, and people reply to that email, it sends the email to a different account of mine than the one I had sent the email from.

- There is nowhere that I can find in the Preferences to set a "reply to" address.
- Apple's support documents indicate that the "reply to" address would be the address your email was sent from (makes sense) unless you type a different address in the "Reply To" field.
- Even when I typed the address I was sending from into the "Reply To" field, the receiver of the email STILL had the different email show up when they hit reply.

I also tried this in the Terminal, found on an about.com site: "defaults read com.apple.mail UserHeaders"

The response was "The domain/default pair of (/Users/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist, UserHeaders) does not exist" which should mean that there isn't some overriding "Reply To" address set.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks so much all! Happy 2012!

Comment: Have you checked if the Mail is sent from the right account? In a mail composition window, there should be a drop down box, which lets you choose the mail account to use. You can also set the default mail account to use in Mail.app's preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am using the email I want in the drop down box of the composition window. I also have set in Preferences -> Composing -> Send new messages from: the email address I want. It is just the "reply to" that is somehow getting changed.   =/

Comment: In the accounts preference window, try dragging the account you want on the top of the drop down list to the top of the listed accounts there. I would assume that what you did (" Preferences -> Composing -> Send new messages from: the email address I want") would do it but if memory serves dragging accounts was an earlier way to do this or do something like it.

Comment: Thanks Richard. The one I want to be the main "reply to" account was already on top. I dragged it down and then dragged it back to the top, but as expected it did not fix the issue.   =/

Comment: The account preferences window affects the sent from mail headers and the SMTP server and not reply to

Comment: Try sending a mail to yourself and see what Apple Mail shows as the account you should send to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! It was somewhat obvious... in Preferences -> Accounts there is a setting for "Outgoing Mail Server" and that is where I needed to make some changes. Thanks everyone that tried to help!

Comment: However that should not affect reply-to header which you set i9n the compose window for mail